# Removing a warning after passing array by parameter (C language)

Tags: c, arrays

The following code passes an array as a parameter from a process of main (called `process`) into another process (called `subprocess`). It simulates behavior I want to achieve in code of my own: `subprocess` fills a string array with the correct strings and then returns them to `process` for... processing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void preprocess(char input[10][10]) {
        int i;
        char temp[10];
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                scanf("%s", &temp);
                strcpy(input[i], temp);
        }
}

void process() {
        int i;
        char strings[10][10];
        preprocess(strings);
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                printf("%s\n", strings[i]);
        }
}

int main() {
        process();
        return 0;
}
```

My question: this code generates a warning and I'm not 100% sure about it. Can someone help me remove the warning and clear this code of booby traps?

**EDIT**: The warning was:

```
warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'char (*)[10]'
```

Comment: What's the warning?

Comment: @Paul it's about the type of argument expected by scanf - it should be char* and not char(*)[10]. Also, what the hell is with people downvoting correct, honest questions? -_-

Comment: Probably because you didn't include the warning in your question, so nobody can tell what problem you're having.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Fair enough. :/ It's extremely irritating as a new user to be subject to silent downvotes over something that small - it's not the reputation, it's the disdain.

Comment: It's not small - a question about removing a warning is seriously ill-formed if it doesn't actually include the warning. If you edit your question to improve it, it's likely you'll get some compensating upvotes.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths It really isn't the upvotes. Also, yes, I suppose it might be some effort to put the code into a compiler - maybe other people are fast enough that that really is a slowdown for them. For me, it'd be my first instinct, so I didn't think of that.

Comment: @Chris it is not about the effort/time required to put the code into a compiler. It is reproducibility. Depending on your target/platform/compiler different people might see different warnings. Some might not even see any. So to discuss the problem __you__ are having, you should show what warnings you are getting.

Comment: It's exrememy irritating as a experinced user to continually have to deal with "doesn't work" questions without details of why it doesn't work:(  It's the equivalent of emailing your doctor with "I'm sick, what shall I do?".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter you pass in to `scanf` is incorrect.  The `%s` format specifier expects a pointer to the first element of an array of `char`.  What you're passing in is the address of the array.

Remove the address-of operator `&` from the `scanf` call.  When an array is passed to a function, it decays to a pointer to the first element.

```
scanf("%9s", temp);
```

The number in the format specifier gives the maximum number of characters to be read.  This prevent a potential buffer overflow of `temp`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
scanf("%s", temp);
```

not

```
scanf("%s", &temp);
```